# PHP Write HTML tags into file and display it

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, comments

I want to make a simple comment system in PHP and my problem is when the user type '<' it disappear because it takes it to HTML code and mess my code.
So what I need to do, when the user type this into the textarea: <stdio.h>, and post it, it should appear as <stdio.h>.

My PHP code:

I want to make a simple comment system in PHP and my problem is when the user type '<' it disappear because it takes it to HTML code and mess my code.
So what I need to do, when the user type this into the textarea: <stdio.h>, and post it, it should appear as <stdio.h>.

My PHP code:

```
<form method="post" name="formc" id="formc" >
    <textarea name="txtmsg" id="txtmsg" cols="25" rows="5" placeholder="Write something!" required="required"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /> 
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
    $com  = $_POST[ "txtmsg" ];
    $file = fopen( "inrg.txt", "a" );
    fwrite( $file, "<em>Anonymous:</em>" );
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= strlen( $com ) - 1; $i++ ) {
        fwrite( $file, $com[ $i ] );
        if ( $i % 37 == 0 && $i != 0 ) fwrite( $file);
    }          
    fwrite( $file, "<br>" );
    fwrite( $file, "<em>Sent: ".date('Y F j, H:i:s')."</em>");
    fclose( $file );

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="";</script>'; // Add here
}
?>
    <br>
</form>
<?php
if (file_exists("inrg.txt")) {
    $file = fopen( "inrg.txt", "r" );
    echo fread( $file, filesize( "inrg.txt" ) );
    fclose( $file );
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look to https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars ?

Comment: And why are you writing the file 1 byte at a time?

Comment: @CarlosM.Hernández Thank you, it's useful but is there any way or is it even possible to check what the user typed into the textarea and if its contains '>' or '<' change it to '&lt;' and '&gt;' ?

Comment: You could do a replace, you should validate all user input before doing anything with POST data in general, so before using $_POST['txtMsg'], check for special characters and replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering why you are writing the file one byte at a time, there must be some really dodgy sample code out there somewhere.
If you use `htmlspecialchars()` it will convert special characters to HTML entities

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) ) {
    
    $file = fopen( "inrg.txt", "a" );
    fwrite( $file, "<em>Anonymous:</em>" );
    fwrite( $file, htmlspecialchars( $_POST['txtmsg'] ));
    fwrite( $file, "<br>" );
    fwrite( $file, "<em>Sent: ".date('Y F j, H:i:s')."</em>");
    fclose( $file );
}
```

RESULT in File

```
<em>Anonymous:</em>include &lt;stdio.h&gt;<br><em>Sent: 2021 January 14, 18:01:54</em>
```

> PHP Manual [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
>
> And if you need it 
> PHP Manual [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)